# Heap sort , about the implementation of method involving range

Tags: function, range, heapsort

What does the -1, -1 in range(n, -1, -1) do, I have encountered this same pattern and implementation with various sorting algo, and it's confusing me so much. Any answers would be appreciated! thank you in advance - NewCoder

-SAMPLE CODE-

def build_max_heap(A):

```
n = len(A)
for i in range(n, -1,-1):
    max_heapify(A,n, i)
for i in range(n-1,0,-1):
    A[0],A[i]=A[i],A[0]
    max_heapify(A,i,0)
```

A=[33,35,42,10,7,8,14,19,48]

build_max_heap(A)

print(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `range` is `range(start, stop[, step])`.

The `range` function in `range(n, -1, -1)` accept 3 argument:

'n' as the start index of the range object

the first '-1' as the end index of the range object

the second '-1' as the move step of the range object

So `range(n, -1, -1)` basic means construct a sequence of [n, n-1, ..., 1, 0].

For more you can refer to [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)